# Adding section index headers for A to Z UITableView scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to add some section headers for a contacts table view. I have a list of contacts in an `Array` which might be like this:

Bill Apple
Borat
Steve Test

I have added the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let currentCollation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation() as UILocalizedIndexedCollation
    let sectionTitles = currentCollation.sectionTitles as NSArray
    return sectionTitles.objectAtIndex(section) as? String
}

func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    let currentCollation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation() as UILocalizedIndexedCollation
    return currentCollation.sectionIndexTitles as [String]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    let currentCollation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation() as UILocalizedIndexedCollation
    return currentCollation.sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex(index)
}
```

This gets the A-Z headings to show up. However as there is only one section and one array holding the contacts the actual functionality does not work.

Should we be sorting the `Array` into an alphabetised `Array` in some sort? So that it has multiple sections? Or is there an easier way to approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should we be sorting the Array into an alphabetised Array in some sort? So that it has multiple sections?

Yes.

You added the delegate methods for the section index, but you didn't show any code that actually performed the collation.

Here's [some sample code from NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uilocalizedindexedcollation/) showing how to use `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` to collate an array of objects (e.g., contacts) into an array of sections of objects (e.g., contacts grouped by section):

```
let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation()
var sections: [[AnyObject]] = []
var objects: [AnyObject] = [] {
    didSet {
        let selector: Selector = "localizedTitle"
        sections = Array(count: collation.sectionTitles.count, repeatedValue: [])

        let sortedObjects = collation.sortedArrayFromArray(objects, collationStringSelector: selector)
        for object in sortedObjects {
            let sectionNumber = collation.sectionForObject(object, collationStringSelector: selector)
            sections[sectionNumber].append(object)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

You'll also want to update your remaining tableView delegates to use the `sections` array:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let contact = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    ...
}
```

FYI, you can simplify your delegate code by assigning the collation property to your view controller, instead of repeatedly declaring a local variable for the (current) collation inside each delegate method.  For example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {
    return collation.sectionTitles[section]
}
```

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks for that very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The tableview is very easy to handle, if you prepare your data in a structure organized like your display.

As you know, you do not receive the section header in your delegate, but the IndexPath. So, it is most convenient to restructure your data to be accessible by IndexPath.

- Keep your data list in a backing store, that is not directly used for the table view. This is either on the server for online applications or in managed data for offline applications or held in memory if the data is not too big. The backing store is optimized for searching and filtering.
- create a `NSArray<DataNode*>` for the sections. Order the array as your table will be ordered.
- in each `DataNode`, you have meta-data, like the title of the section, collapsed information etc. and real data, like the section header node (if there is such a thing) and the children of the section as the `NSArray<DataNode*>` of addresses. Again, ordered in the way you want them in display.

All delegate functions are now a pice of cake and more or less reduce to

```
tableData.count  // count of sections
tableData[indexPath.section] // section header data
tableData[indexPath.section].children.count // rows in section
tableData[indexPath.section].children[indexPath.row]  // row data
```

If you have a "live-filter" function, where the user types a few chars and you want to reduce the list to the matches, you actually rebuild the `DataNode` lists from your original data list.

```
-(void) buildSearchresult:(NSString *)criteria {
    NSArray *result = [backingListService findWithCriteria:criteria];
    NSArray *nodes = [displayListService structureResult:result withOption:OPTAlphaSort];
    [[NotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:@"listUpdate" object:nodes];
}
```

Run the search and restructuring of the data in the background and send the new list with NotificationCenter to the delegate.

The delegate will catch the updated list and put it in place for the `[self.tableView reloadData]`:

```
-(void)onUpdateListData:(NSNotification *)mesg {
    NSArray *nodes = mesg.object;

    self.displayData = nodes;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This is how I do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @StuartM here is an exemple in Objective-C you'll can re-write in Swift. I post it because this algo works well. As you can see algo is called in the `numberOfsectionsInTableView` of UITableView's delegate so index is recalculate each time because of index and number of section depending of the array's content.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Create sections from raw list of all objects
    return [self numberOfsectionForObjectsList];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfsectionForObjectsList
{

    NSMutableArray *tempAllObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *tempDigitsSection = nil;
    NSMutableArray *tempLetterSection = nil;
    NSMutableArray *tempIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    BOOL digitIndexCreated = NO;
    NSString *currentLetter = nil;

    for (id *object in allObjectsList)
    {
        if ([object login].length > 0)
        {
            NSString *firstLetter = [[object login] substringToIndex:1];
            NSCharacterSet *notDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
            if ([firstLetter rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound) // firstLetter is a digit, not a letter
            {
                if (digitIndexCreated == NO)
                {
                    [tempIndex insertObject:@"#" atIndex:0];
                    tempDigitsSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    digitIndexCreated = YES;
                }

                [tempDigitsSection addObject:object];
            }
            else // firstLetter is a letter, not a digit
            {
                if ([firstLetter caseInsensitiveCompare:currentLetter] == NSOrderedSame) // Always the same first letter = same section
                {
                    [tempLetterSection addObject:object];
                }
                else // New first letter = new section
                {
                    if (tempLetterSection == nil)
                    {
                        tempLetterSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                        [tempIndex addObject:[firstLetter uppercaseString]];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [tempAllObjects addObject:[tempLetterSection copy]];
                        [tempIndex addObject:[firstLetter uppercaseString]];
                        tempLetterSection = nil;
                        tempLetterSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    }

                    [tempLetterSection addObject:object];
                    currentLetter = firstLetter;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (tempDigitsSection != nil)
    {
        [tempAllObjects insertObject:tempDigitsSection atIndex:0];
    }
    if (tempLetterSection != nil)
    {
        [tempAllObjects addObject:tempLetterSection];
    }

    indexesList = [tempIndex copy];
    allObjectsList = nil;
    allObjectsList = [tempAllObjects copy];

    if ([allObjectsList count] > 0)
    {
        return [allObjectsList count];
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you even if it could be optimized ^^